# Celery - purge a specific queue using Redis from Python script

Tags: python, celery

I'm aware of Celery's command-line options:

```
celery -A my_app purge -Q queue_name
```

But I am looking for a way to purge `queue_name` from my Python app with Celery, something along the lines of:

```
def start_chunk(num_of_objs):
    # clear current queue before starting here
    RELEVANT CODE HERE TO PURGE queue_name
    for num in num_of_objcts:
         some_task.apply_async(kwargs={'num': num}, queue="queue_name")
```

Note, I'm aware of this:

```
from proj.celery import app
app.control.purge()
```

But as I understand this [purges all queues](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.control.html#celery.app.control.Control.purge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit, it is little bit difficult to get it right. But the first thing you should look at for hints how to solve this problem is bin/purge.py (that is what I've done). After analysing the mentioned file, I think something like the following should work:

```
from celery.app.base import Celery
from yourproject import celery_app


def purge_queue(app: Celery, queue_name: str):
    with app.connection_for_write() as conn:
        conn.default_channel.queue_purge(queue_name)


purge_queue(celery_app, "celery")  # purge the "celery" queue
```

The above is more/less what `celery -A yourproject.celery_app purge -Q celery` does.

Comment: thanks for your effort. This does seem to work! (haven't tested if it purges all other queues yet) any advantages to using this vs. [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58524838/5013234) I just posted?

Comment: I have now tested. This doesn't purge tasks in other queues, only the one specified. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to call the purge command through the `os`, we must use the `-f` flag:

```py
import os
os.system("celery -A app_name purge -Q queue_name -f")
```

I don't know if there are any cons to this compared to [DejanLekic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58522960/5013234), which looks cleaner.

Comment: How/why is this any different from simply running the purge command in the shell?? I thought you explicitly wanted to purge particular queue *programmatically*...

Comment: @DejanLekic this allows me to schedule the purge right before I send more tasks in.

Comment: If you have to schedule purge of the queue(s), then you are doing something wrong, but that is off-topic...

Comment: @DejanLekic I wouldn’t be too quick to make this kind of blanket statement. Suppose TASK_A has to process 5000 oldest objs in DB every hour. But sometimes things take a little longer and if it doesn’t finish in time, then it will inevitably process the same obj twice unnecessarily. Can’t we solve this by purging/resetting the queue before firing the next batch?

Comment: @DejanLekic I still think your answer is better, I’m curious to hear why mine is so wrong. You obviously know Celery better than me.